# How to chagne admin site URL in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, multi-tenant

I've something like kailash.sharepoint.com for which the admin site URL will be kailash-admin.sharepoint.com . I want to change that particular admin site URL to something like **kailashadmin.sharepoint.com** .I thought this was **impossible**, I've seen one of my customer is having a URL like this, so it is **possible** in Office 365 SharePoint. I don't want **redirecting**, I completely want to change it to a new URL without **'-admin'** in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SharePoint Online not supported to change Admin Site url.

This is by design with this format:

```
https://Tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
```